# Yii2: Get values to update form in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I am using Yii2 modal to update a form in modal window but I am unable to fetch the values to be already filled in the form.

In this screen-shot link below:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f957qq367

When I click on edit option, It takes me to the update form which is opened in a modal window. But this form shows empty values in all fields. I want to update the form.

Please find this in this screen-shot below:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f257qqscb

This is the snippet for what I have tried yet:

```
<?php

use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

Modal::begin([
    'id'=>'modalEdit',
    //'header' => '<h2>Hello world</h2>',
    'size'=> 'modal-lg',
    //'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'click me'],
]);

    $newmodel = new Backlog();
   // $newmodel->id;
    echo $this->render('/backlog/update', ['model' => $newmodel]);

Modal::end();


        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'nav-pills navbar-right'],
            'encodeLabels' => false,
            'items' => [
            ['label' => '', 'items' => [

                ['label' => '<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit" style="cursor: pointer;">Edit</span>','url' => 'javascript:void(0);'],
                '<li class="divider"></li>',
                ['label' => '<span>Assign</span>', 'url' => ['#']],
                '<li class="divider"></li>',
                ['label' => '<span>Convert To Backlog</span>', 'url' => ['#']],
                '<li class="divider"></li>',
                ['label' => '<span>Close</span>', 'url' => ['#']],
            ]],
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem using javascript and ajax loading :

```
$(document).on("click",".edit-backlog",function(e){

var back_l_id=$(this).attr("b-id");
var modal_body=$("#modalEdit").find(".modal-body");

$.ajax({
    url:getAjaxUrl('backlog','update'),
    data:{'id':back_l_id},
    success:function(res){
       //console.log(res);
        modal_body.html(res);
    }
});



});
```

I added a class `.edit-backlog` to span and get the `id` ("b-id") and used in the above script. Hope this answer helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

if Backlog is an ActiveRecord Replace the Line with this.

```
$newmodel = Backlog::findOne(['ID'=>$id]);
```

Comment: It won't work. And this gives the error:Call to a member function getActiveValidators() on null